# How to add app_name.entitlements file in Xcode 7 for Homekit

Tags: ios, entitlements, homekit, code-signing-entitlements, ios-homekit

I am developing application which contains Homekit capability. I want to add "com.apple.developer.homekit" in entitlements file. How do I add .entitlements file for the application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You add it in your project. Click on your project, select your target, Go to Capabilities.  You will find HomeKit and turn in ON.  This will add it to your AppID in the member developer center and add an entitlement file and also add it to your frameworks.